# MongoDB - Reduce WiredTiger Filesize

Tags: git, mongodb, wiredtiger

I'm making a web app with the MEAN Stack, and I'm having issues with version control.

I'm trying to push to a repo on Github Enterprise, and because of the "apparent" sizes of my WiredTiger files
[(which you can see here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auJRI.png)

I'm getting this error:

> remote: error: File data/db/journal/WiredTigerPreplog.0000000002 is 100.00 MB; this exceeds GitHub Enterprise's file size limit of 100.00 MB

Is there anyway to configure these files to hold less "apparent" space??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would not store binary files into a source code management system. While git *has* [Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com), checking in binary files of MongoDB is not exactly a good idea. Usually, you would check in a text file representation of your initial data (for example JSON or CVS) and add it to your database on startup of your application.

If you *really* need to keep the database files for deployment, then I would take a different approach and use Docker: Fill your database, stop the container, [`docker commit` the container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) and use the resulting container for deployment. Note that this is not ideal, either.

Answer (score 0):

These are journaling files from mongodb, instead of pushing these files to version control. Store it on some 3rd party hosting provider or locally if the hosted server has enough space for production environment. For dev environments, this should be disabled. If you don't need journaling, you can disable from mongo conf file. Also, i would suggest to read [Journaling in Mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/journaling/)